# Is there a Kronecker delta in Julia?

Tags: julia

If I have some declared some Points in Julia (p_1,...,p_n). Is there some function or algorithm for kronecker delta (`f_i(p_j)=1 if i=j` and `f_i(p_j)=0 if i != j`)

It would be very helpful.

Thank you so much.

Comment: simply `δ = Int∘==`?  Heck you might not even need the `Int`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want a kronecker delta **function** you can use the `==(x,y)` function (as indicated by @mbauman in the comments).

```
julia> δ(x,y) = ==(x,y)
δ (generic function with 1 method)

julia> δ(1,1)
true

julia> δ(1,2)
false
```

Note that this returns `true` or `false` instead of `1` and `0` but the former are essentially equal to the latter and will behave in the same way, for example `==(1,1) * 2` will give `2`. In fact, `true isa Integer` in Julia.

Another option might be to use `I` the (lazy) identity **matrix** built into Julia (`LinearAlgebra` that is):

```
julia> using LinearAlgebra

julia> I[1,1]
true

julia> I[1,2]
false
```

Comment: How can that be extended to an arbitrary number of arguments `n`?

Answer (score 0):

For an arbitrary number of arguments, you can do:

```
δ(x, y) = ==(x, y)

function δ(x, y, z...)
    !δ(x, y) && return false
    for i in z
        !δ(x, i) && return false
    end
    return true
end
```

or if you make the convention that `δ(x) := true`:

```
δ(x, y) = ==(x, y)

function δ(z...)
    for i in z
        !δ(z[1], i) && return false
    end
    return true
end
```